# Load balancing Search service application Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint farm with 2 front end servers and two application servers.
The search service application is going to used very heavily. So I need to ensure that the search service application is load balanced.

I have created a search service application

How do I load balance it on another application server.

1. Do I need the application and Load balancer service
2. start the search service only on both the application services
3. Will this ensure that the service application is load balanced.

Answer (score 1):

In order to create a redundant topology for load balancing and high availability. You need to make sure Search topology properly configured.

- As long as same services are running on multiple servers, SharePoint
  will use its internal Load Balancer.

You need to  deploy Admin Component, Crawl Component, Analytics Processing Component, Content Processing Component and Index Partition on more than 1 Application Servers and run Query Processing Component on the Web Front End Servers.

read more over here for information:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ptsblog/archive/2013/09/19/configuring-sharepoint-2013-search-with-powershell.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtaylor/archive/2011/02/23/sharepoint-2010-service-application-load-balancer.aspx